# Create string line comma separated

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have 6 bool "categories":

```
Category0, Category1, Category2, Category3, Category4, Category5.
```

I also have a "String ListCat" variable. This variable must look like something like:

```
ListCat = "0,1,2,3,4,5"
```

Where "0" is displayed if Category0 = true, "1" if category1 = true...

For exemple :

```
Categorie0 = true;
Catgorie1 = true;
Categorie5 = true;
```

Then ListCat would be like :

```
ListCat ="0,1,5"
```

I have to do this to complete this query :

```
string StSQL = @"SELECT [Type Jour] FROM CodificationTypesJour where Categorie IN (" + ListCat + ");
```

How can I do that, with the commas included?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Category0-5 is there any control - or boolean property ?

Comment: Use [Parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query).

Comment: Boolean property. I can't change the query unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of values you want to add to result, then join them using [String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8).

For example if you have:

```
bool category0 = true,
     category1 = true,
     category2 = false,
     category3 = false,
     category4 = false,
     category5 = true;
```

then you can create an array:

```
string[] values = 
{
    category0 ? "0" : null,
    category1 ? "1" : null,
    category2 ? "2" : null,
    category3 ? "3" : null,
    category4 ? "4" : null,
    category5 ? "5" : null
};
```

and the result will be:

```
var result = string.Join(",", values.Where(s => s != null));

// output: "0,1,5"
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. Litterally. Thanks for this string.join method !